# How to plot time on the y axis correctly using python matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two lists containing the sunset and sunrise times and the corresponding dates.
It looks like:

```py
sunrises = ['06:30', '06:28', '06:27', ...]
dates = ['3.21', '3.22', '3.23', ...]
```

I want to make a plot of the sunrise times as the Y axis and the dates as the X axis.
Simply using

```py
ax.plot(dates, sunrises)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator(7))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator(7))
plt.show()
```

can plot the dates correctly, but the time is wrong:
[image: actual plot]

And actually, the sunrise time isn't supposed to be a straight line.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you trying to plot these as a line chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your `sunrises` are not numerical. I'm assuming you'd want them in a form such that `"6:30"` means `6.5`. Which is calculated below:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sunrises = ['06:30', '06:28', '06:27']
# This converts to decimals
sunrises = [float(x[0:2])+(float(x[-2:])/60) for x in sunrises]
dates = ['3.21', '3.22', '3.23']

plt.plot(sunrises, dates)
plt.xlabel('sunrises')
plt.ylabel('dates')
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot]

---

Note, your `dates` are being treated as decimals. Is this correct?

Comment: Thanks freddy, this is a great idea. Maybe I can transform the times to floats. But in this program I want to still display the time labels as the format %H:%M.

Comment: No problem Jason, The other answer keeps the labels in `%H:%M` format

Answer (score 4):

You need to transform the datetime in string format to the format that `matplotlib` can comprehend by using `datetime`

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib as mpl
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

sunrises = ['06:30', '06:28', '06:27',]
sunrises_dt = [datetime.strptime(item,'%H:%M') for item in sunrises]
dates = ['3.21', '3.22', '3.23',]

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(dates, sunrises_dt)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M',))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mpl.ticker.MultipleLocator(1))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I'd recommend doing the same to `dates` as well: convert with `datetime.strptime(item,'%m.%d')` and format `ax.xaxis` with `mdates.DateFormatter('%m.%d')`

Comment: Wow, thanks! Now the data finally plots correctly.